# Pandas: convert datetimeindex to periodindex?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a bunch of data from users logging events, and the data is of type 0, 1, or 2. These all hence form irregular time series. I have brought them into `pandas Series`, one for each data type, with a data time index. I have also resampled with `ffill` and applying `asfreq` to my data types.

However, I would like to be able to calculate cross correlation functions and run regressions. It seems like the easiest way to get there would be to convert my Series indices to `period indices` so that even if times are not exactly the same, they will be in the same period and so will share an index. **How can I convert my date time indices to period indices?**

Here's what my series look like:

Series 0:

```
2014-10-30 19:27:04.330    160
2014-10-30 22:10:32.682     88
2014-10-31 00:43:43.806    128
2014-10-31 03:40:07.164     89
2014-10-31 11:51:03.867     66
2014-10-31 17:58:01.835     84
2014-10-31 20:56:20.770    104
2014-10-31 21:58:41.153     82
2014-10-31 23:26:51.695     95
dtype: float64
```

Series 1:

```
2016-02-06 00:11:00.910     50
2016-02-07 05:06:21.677     30
2016-02-07 21:26:05.312     26
2016-02-10 18:14:03.762    100
2016-02-11 00:56:34.635     20
2016-02-12 03:20:44.296     15
2016-02-12 18:41:54.061     90
2016-02-13 17:08:00.000     25
2016-02-13 19:26:01.988     40
dtype: float64
```

Series 2 looks similar. Series 0 starts substantially earlier than the others, but all three do have overlapping dates.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Again, still way to vague. Would you like the period to be minutely, hourly, daily, monthly, et cetera? How do you handle 'collisions'? Take the mean of the values? How do you fill missing values: forward/back fill, mean-fill, interpolate?

Comment: Use `to_period`, documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-between-representations).